# OpenVPN - Client is not able to connect to the server from command line

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I set up an OpenVPN server myself. My client system is using Ubuntu 16.04. 
 **I can successfully connect the client** to the VPN server using `network-manager` UI. But when I try to connect to the VPN from the terminal, it is not getting connected.

This is the command I am using to connect:

```
sudo openvpn --config client1.ovpn
```

This is the log generated by running the command (last few lines):

```
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlp2s0 HWADDR=b0:c0:90:a4:4e:9c
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1572 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5 init
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.5
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 GID set to nogroup
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 UID set to nobody
Tue Aug 22 15:42:17 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Any clues on whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of your log your VPN is connecting successfully. So going on the assumption that you are unable to connect to whatever is on the remote side of your VPN it might be that network manager is setting your default route to be the VPN.

Try adding

```
redirect-gateway def1
```

To your client config to see if it resolves the issue. This option is outlined here: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html